# Can not boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot

Good afternoon, I'm new to Ubuntu and wanted to empty my trash.  Since the process was aborted, I restarted my PC.  After that this error appeared:

`/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks`

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix the error?

Comment: More an information message then an error. I got blasted once before for calling this an error. Anyway your system will run fine and I am sure it does right now with this message. Did you search this site for question the same as yours there are many.

Comment: Indeed, **NOT and error**. Now, if the problem is the graphical desktop not coming up then please [edit] the question and describe that fact alongside hardware specifications and the reason why the process was aborted and how... N.B - Have you error checked the drive already?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Yes, I've already searched for this topic but haven't found a solution.  Unfortunately, my PC has been stuck in this state for half an hour now and the graphical desktop is not coming up.  Is it possible that the boot process still continues?

It is an HP ZBOOK with an intel core i7.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, I did do a storage Test via the HP PC Hardware Disgnostic UEFI

Comment: Hardware diagnostics checks the drive health only, not logical errors that likely occurred due to an abrupt shutdown or reboot.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. Ist there a way to error check the drive for logical errors?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

While this message was shown I pressed `strg+alt+f2`.  There I was
shown a message that there was no more memory available.
I pressed
`strg+c` and got into the console.   After entering my username and
password, I deleted some files and restarted my PC.

Voila, everything
is running.